# Why does <input type='range'/> have the wrong size in terms of content flow?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div id='div-1' style='background:blue; height:100%'>
  <input id='input-1' type='range' style='height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0; border: 0'/>
</div>

<div id='div-2' style='background:red; height:fit-content; fit-content'>
  <input id='input-2' type='range' style='margin:0; padding: 0; border: 0'/>
</div>
```

In both cases, the `div` is taller than the `input` by 2.5px (Firefox) to 3px (Chrome), no matter what I do (aside from explicitly setting the size of both).  Why does `input` seem to have some secret unchangeable padding that I cannot control (across all browsers, but not the same amount across all browsers)?

I'm trying to ensure that the `div` is the exact same size as the `input`, yet no matter what I do I cannot get them to be sized the same without doing some sketchy hard-coding of values (in a very browser-dependent fashion).

I have tried an assortment of "reset" tricks to try to get the `input` element to either fit its parent or for the parent to fit the input, but there always is some extra secret padding/margin below the `input`.

Comment: Can you please simplfy, what you want to achieve and what issue are you facing

Comment: I want (`div-1` & `input-1`) or (`div-2` & `input-2`) to have the same height, without having to explicitly specify the height of one of them and without doing browser-specific fixes (like a margin of -2 pixels in chrome and -2.5 in FF).

Comment: try to add !important

Comment: No such luck.  I tried adding it to everything I could think of, but maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `input` is `inline-block`. The default is baseline alignment. The larger the text, the more space below it. `flex` and `grid` Both have changed the document flow alignment, so there is no space below.

```css
/* div {
  font-size: 0;
}*/

#input-1 {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id='div-1' style='background:blue; height:100%'>
  <input id='input-1' type='range' style='height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0; border: 0'/>javascript
</div>

<div id='div-2' style='background:red; height:fit-content;'>
  <input id='input-2' type='range' style='margin:0; padding: 0; border: 0'/>javascript
</div>
```

I looked it up, and the border can be changed.
The following code only works in firefox.

```css
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #def3f8, inset 0 0.125em 0.125em #0d1112;
}

input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 0.125em rgba(205, 224, 230, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0.125em 0.125em #3b4547;
}

input[type='range']::-moz-range-progress {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, green, white 100%, white);
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-width: 0; /* Set border-width */
}
input[type='range'] {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input id='input-2' type='range'/>
```

Comment: I think that answers the main question, thanks!  In Firefox there is still a 1px border that won't go away, but that feels like a separate question (if you happen to know the answer, that would be great though).

Comment: @Micah Zoltu In Firefox, 1px is a blank area belonging to <input type="range">, which is the space reserved by the designer of this graphic. I posted two image above, which you may understand.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that when you look at in Firefox inspector at the `input` element it has a `border-width:1px` despite having set it explicitly to `0` in the inline style.

Comment: @Micah Zoltu Sorry, I answered a question earlier is error. The above code has been modified.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:flex` or `display:grid`.

After more fiddling, I found out that if I set the wrapper `div` to `display:flex` or `display:grid` the problem goes away.  I would still like to better understand *why* this problem is occurring, or if there are any other workarounds but if no one else provides an answer within a couple days I'll mark this as the answer.